# Way to use validator.js with ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, validation

I want to use validator.js to do some validation on my form input.
I just want to know what is the best way to use it, or if it exist an other lib to do validation whitout changing my html.

Comment: You can use https://redux-form.com/8.1.0/ if you have redux.

Comment: Easiest way is to use HTML5 validation which handles it for you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation. Otherwise you check for errors on change, or blur, or submit, and show them, what do you not understand about that?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to `install validator.js from npm`.

`npm install validator`

Usage:

```js
import validator from 'validator';

// example
validator.isEmail('foo@bar.com'); // use it in handleChange or functions being called
```

I hope this helps. Here is the link to [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator)